# Creating a new column containing specified ranges based on values in a column of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Pl consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I want to specify ranges for the values, for eg:

```
0 : range(0,6)
1 : range(6, 11)
```

such that I have the output dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  "val":[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({"col":[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

rngd={ 0:list(range(0,6)), 1:list(range(6, 11))}

l=[]
j=0

for i in range(len(b['col'])):
  if i==0 or b['col'][i]==b['col'][(i-1)] :
    l.append(rngd[b['col'][i]][j])
  


  else:
    j=0
    l.append(rngd[b['col'][i]][j])
  j+=1
```